# Есть ли разница между массивами, если второй инициализируется нолями?

Tags: c#, массивы, инициализация

```
        int[] nums1 = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            nums1[i] = 0;
        }
```

и второй

```
        int[] nums2 = new int[10];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, разница есть. Ссылки на память будут разными. Возможно еще HashCode тоже разный будет.

Comment: Какой-то странный вопрос, как-будто вопрос касается длины массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// это 2 разных массива
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // False
// имеющих одинаковое содержимое
Console.WriteLine(a.SequenceEqual(b)); // True
```

Если вопрос про то, имеет ли смысл инициализировать массив нулями, то нет, не имеет